# Sql query to count ads added in the last 7 days

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have made this working sql query to count the ads the user has in total ->

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `table_name` WHERE `user_id` = 20;
```

So this shows how many ads the user has in total. What I want to add is how many ads the user added in the last 7 days... so I have a column in `table_name` called "created_date"... so can somebody please help me how to count the user ads by "created_date" from now to last 7 days please?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   table_name
WHERE  user_id = 20 AND created_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

More generally, look at [MySQL's date functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for all sorts of advanced date handling.

Comment: thank you, this worked great. I remember I tried something like this, but it gave me a error syntax... thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM table_name
WHERE user_id = 20 AND created_date > (NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Comment: thank you, this worked great. I remember I tried something like this, but it gave me a error syntax... thank you

Comment: @Fahim Parkar thank you for answer. That worked perfect. And how do we get the next 7 days in the future? i tried + instead of -  but it dididn't work. Thanks!

Comment: @user2060451 : for next week use `WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAYS)`